# Tymeleaf Spring boot using javascript append html not woking click event

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

My Basket.js file

```
  function test(){
        let baskets = document.querySelectorAll('.basket');
        baskets.forEach((basket) => {
            $(basket).on("click",function(event){
                console.log("clicked")
                let productId;
                let productName;
                let productDiscount;
                let productPrice;
                let productImage;
                let check = $(".gridDisable").attr("id");
                if (check === "list") {
                    let parentDataSort = $(this).closest(".dateSort");
                    productId = parseInt(parentDataSort.find('.cartProduct').val())
                    productDiscount = $(this).closest(".dateSort").data("discount");
                    productName = parentDataSort.data("name");
                    productDiscount = parentDataSort.data("discount");
                    productPrice = productDiscount ? parentDataSort.find(".discountResult").data("result") : parentDataSort.data("price");
                    productImage = parentDataSort.find('.product-img-file').attr('src');
                } else {
                    let parentDataColumn = $(this).closest(".dateSortColumn");
                    productId = parseInt(parentDataColumn.find('.cartProduct').val())
                    productDiscount = $(this).closest(".dateSortColumn").data("discount");
                    productName = parentDataColumn.data("name");
                    productDiscount = parentDataColumn.data("discount");
                    productPrice = productDiscount ? parentDataColumn.find(".discountResult").data("result") : parentDataColumn.data("price");
                    productImage = parentDataColumn.find('.product-image').attr('src');
                }
                addToBasket(productId, productName, productPrice, productImage);
            })
        })
    }

    test();

    function addToBasket(productId, productName, productPrice, productImage) {
        let cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
        let pCart = JSON.parse(cart) != null ? JSON.parse(cart) : [];
        let present_or_not = pCart.findIndex(item => item.productId === productId);
        if (cart == null || present_or_not == null || present_or_not === -1) {
            let product = {
                productId: productId,
                productName: productName,
                pPrice: productPrice,
                quantity: 1,
                image: productImage
            };
            pCart.push(product);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pCart));
        } else {
            let actual_stored_product = pCart[present_or_not];
            pCart.splice(present_or_not, 1);
            let actual_qty = actual_stored_product.quantity == null || actual_stored_product.quantity === "" ? 0 : actual_stored_product.quantity;
            actual_stored_product.quantity = parseInt(actual_qty) + 1;
            pCart.push(actual_stored_product);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pCart));
        }
        swal({
            title: "Səbətə əlavə olundu",
            icon: "success",
            button: "Bağla",
        });

        let count = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).length;
        $(".basket_count").text(count);
    }
```

My active.js file

```
  function showFilteredPriceProduct(min, max, isNew) {
         $.get("/product/price?min=" + min + "&max=" + max + "&isNew=" + isNew, function (data) {
             $("#column").empty();
            $("#grid").empty();
            if (data.data.length <= 10) {
                $("#pagen").hide();
            } else {
                $("#pagen").show();
            }
            $.each(data.data, function (key, v) {
                let item_content = `<div class="col-md-12 ml-4 my-3 py-2 dateSortColumn" data-name="${v.name}" data-price="${v.price}" data-discount="${v.isDiscount}">
                                        ${v.isNew ? `<div class="ribbon text-center" >Yeni<br></div>` : `<small style="display:none !important"></small>`}
                                        ${v.isDiscount ? `<div class="discount">- ${v.discount} %</div>` : `<small style="display:none !important"></small>`}
                                         <div class="row bg-white">
                                             <div class="col-md-3 mt-1">
                                               <div class="container" id="wishlist">
                                                    <i class="far fa-heart js-heart heart"></i>
                                                  </div>
                                                 <img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded product-image" src="${v.files[0].url}" />
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-md-6 mt-1">
                                                 <a href="/detail/${v.id}"><h5 class="detailLink">${v.name}</h5></a>
                                                 <div class="ratings-cart d-flex flex-row">
                                                     <div class="ratings mr-2">
                                                         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="align-items-center align-content-center col-md-3 border-left mt-1">
                                                 <label>
                                                  <input class="cartProduct" style="visibility: hidden!important;" th:value="${v.id}"
                                                   type="text">
                                                  </label>
                                                 <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
                                                      ${v.isDiscount ? `<div>
                                                           <h4 class="mr-1 product-price discountResult">${v.price - (v.price * v.discount / 100)}.00</h4>
                                                          </div>` : `<h4 class="mr-1 product-price">₼ ${v.price}.00</h4>`}
                                                       ${v.isDiscount ? `<del>
                                                           <h4 style="font-size:14px;" class="mr-1 product-price">₼ ${v.price}.00</h4>
                                                    </del>` : `<small style="display:none;"></small>`}
                                                 </div>
                                                 <h6 class="text-success">Baxış sayı:<small class="productCount">${v.count}</small></h6>
                                                 <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4">
                                                     <button class="btn btn-sm basket" type="button">Səbətə əlavə et</button>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>`


                let grid_items = `<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-xl-6 dateSort" data-name="${v.name}" data-price="${v.price}">
                                     <div class="single-product-wrapper">
                                        ${v.isNew ? `<div class="ribbon text-center" >Yeni<br></div>` : `<small style="display:none !important"></small>`}
                                        ${v.isDiscount ? `<div class="discount">- ${v.discount} %</div>` : `<small style="display:none !important"></small>`}
                                         <div class="product-img">
                                             <img alt="" class="product-img-file" src="${v.files[0].url}" />
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="product-description d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                             <div class="product-meta-data">
                                                 <label>
                                                     <input class="cartProduct" style="visibility: hidden !important;" value="${v.id}" type="text" />
                                                 </label>
                                                 <div class="line"></div>
                                                 <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start dataPrice">
                                                      ${v.isDiscount ? `<div>
                                                       <p class="product-price discountResult"> ₼ ${v.price - (v.price * v.discount / 100)}.00 </p>
                                                      </div>` : ` <p class="product-price">₼ ${v.price}.00 </p>`}
                                                      ${v.isDiscount ? `<del><h4 style="font-size:14px;" class="mr-1 product-price">₼ ${v.price}.00</h4>
                                                         </del>` : `<small style="display:none"></small>`}
                                                 </div>
                                                 <a href="/detail/${v.id}">
                                                     <h6 class="productName">${v.name}</h6>
                                                 </a>
                                                 <button class="basket" type="button">Səbətə əlavə et</button>
                                             </div>

                                             <div class="ratings-cart text-right">
                                                 <div class="ratings">
                                                     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <small> Baxış sayı: <small>${v.count}</small> </small>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
`
                $("#grid").append(grid_items);
                $("#column").append(item_content);
            })
        });
    }
```

Hi everyone my simple project using thymeleaf and javascript code loading my project my add basket  service normal working but sort change sort data returns spring boot backend service and append html code using javascript and jquery click event not working my add basket service

Comment: You can't combine Thymeleaf and JavaScript like this. Keep in mind that Thymeleaf runs first on the server, then JavaScript runs on the client.